# exposing method in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

so I'm finally done with caching in WCF service. Anyways, now this is my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Screen_Data> GetData(DateTime d);
}
```

and this is my class which implements this interface

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
                       AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
   [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor2Minutes")]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?DateTime={DateTime}")]
   public IEnumerable<Screen_Data> GetData(DateTime d)
   {
       ScreenScrapingEntities1 db = new ScreenScrapingEntities1();
       IEnumerable<Screen_Data> sd = from p in db.Screen_Data
                                     where p.DateTime > d
                                     select p;
       return sd;
    }
}
```

This screen_data is a database table and I have generated a ado.net Entity Data Model from the database.

My question is when I try to call this method from a WCF client passing a datetime value, it should return more than 10 rows. I'm not sure how I can return those rows from this method, can someone help me with this code I have written in class, it doesn't even take lambda expressions in linq query.

And this is how I'm calling this `GetData` method from the client

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-31 11:38:29.070");
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
client.GetData(t);
```

this the class generated while creating model

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="ScreenScrapingModel", Name="Screen_Data")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Screen_Data : EntityObject
    {
}
```

Comment: I advice to write your own screen_data class with [data member] attributes. or I don't know but in ado generations should have serializable property

Comment: well this screen data class, wen i'm generating model from database, it automatically comes under datacontract, let me edit the question and show that to u

Comment: what is your question? you need to help for what? are you get any exception? or service call not return anything?

Comment: @Damith check the other answer, which u have answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use your own Dto

```
[DataContract]
public class ScreenDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

try returning  array

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ScreenDto[] GetData(DateTime d);
}
```

Change the method implementation

```
public ScreenDto[] GetData(DateTime d)
   {
       ScreenScrapingEntities1 db = new ScreenScrapingEntities1();
       ScreenDto[] sd = (from p in db.Screen_Data
                            where p.DateTime > d
                            select new ScreenDto()
                            {Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, DateAdded =p.Date)
                            .ToArray();
       return sd; // put break point here, to check return data
    }
```

call it as

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
var results =  client.GetData(t);
```

Start both web service and client application, your web service should be on debug mode, check you get call from client or not, and also the result it return from service side.

Comment: yes it gives me results in service but nothing in client side..some one told me that my screen_data class is not serialize, how do i make them serialize, it is auto generated when i added that model

Comment: thats one approach but what i'm trying to do now rather than model generating classes for me, i'm creating my own classes...this will work, thanks man

Comment: so results are coming in service, but when i check that in client, this result variable contains sth else, not the results which were sent from the service, something like this {ClientWCF.ServiceReference1.Alert[0]}

Comment: Oh its done, I'm using those auto generated files, which are generated by svcutil.exe for the service and now including them in my client application. it worked...thanks damith